# Angular is updating all fields simultaneously when it should just update one

Tags: angular

I have a *ngFor and I'm trying to update a number field on click but it updates all of the items with same value.

In my html:

```
<form *ngFor="let product of products" [formGroup]="myForm" name="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit([product.name], [product.price], int)">
<div id="cartItemsList">
<ul>
<li>
<div name="product_name">{{product.name }}</div>
<div><img src="../assets/images/gallery/{{product.thumbnail}}" /></div>
<div>{{product.price }}</div>
<button class="minus-btn" (click)="minus()" type="button" name="btn">
<img src="../assets/images/minus.svg" alt="minus" /></button>
<input pattern="^(0|\+?[1-9]\d*)$" class="num" name="int" [value]="int" formControlName="int" ng-model="quantity" ng-minlength="0" type="number">
<button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus()" type="button" name="btn">
<img src="../assets/images/plus.svg" alt="plus" /></button>
<button type="submit" class="btnAddAction">Add to Cart</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

in my controller:

```
int: number=1;
  
plus(){
this.int++;
}

minus(){ 
this.int--;
}
```

Comment: Please format your sample code properly, as it is difficult to read.

Comment: i've asked for a code format. I think you will need to implement FormArray as here https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#create-an-array-of-form-controls.

Comment: By formatting do you mean just add indentations to the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

look at what you are doing:  `[value]="int"`

you are using the same global variable "int" for every product of every form.

what you want to do is:

```
<input pattern="^(0|\+?[1-9]\d*)$" class="num" name="int" [value]="product.value" 
formControlName="int" ng-model="quantity" ng-minlength="0" type="number">

<button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus(product)" type="button" name="btn">
```

js:

```
plus(product:any){
  product.value++;
}

minus(product:any){
  product.value--;
}
```

besides that you have placed your ngFor loop on `<form>`, which is probably not what you want. you are going to end up with a whole bunch of forms all named "myForm".

What you probably want, is one form and then have a bunch of products.

Comment: I changed type="number" to type="text" and then the input field displayed NaN. When I used type="number", I got the error: The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

Comment: My ngFor loop needs to be placed on <form> because ngSubmit uses the looped-through values.

Comment: I made changes to my answer. your input can stay number. its the [value] that needs to be tied to a specific product. not tied to a global variable.

Comment: and you might need to initialize all your product.value fields to "1". that may be why you are getting NaN error

Comment: I tried using parseInt but I got the error for the parameter of my plus function: Function implementation name must be 'parseInt'.

Comment: I put my onSubmit function in a click event in the submit button so I could remove the ngFor from the form tag.

Comment: to do `product.value=1` you need to make sure "value" is a property of "product". maybe its some other field. depends how you have your data set up.

Comment: I used product.id and it demonstrated the behaviour that I had predicted. Of course it took the id that was being implemented and incremented or decremented it. So an id that was 4 became 5 when I incremented it one time. A workaround could be to make a product field that holds NULL values so that I could increment them starting at NULL but this seems rather inelegant and convoluted. I wish there was a better solution.

Comment: Thank you, Rick, for all of your helpful advice.